# Convert code to english using List comprehension - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a function english_sentence(sentence) to convert a string of coded words into english. The rules for conversion are simple:

1. If the word starts with a consonant then the weird Latin version is formed by moving the first letter to the end of the word and adding the string "eeoow", eg, turtle -> urtleteeoow
2. If the word starts with a non-consonant character then the weird Latin version is simply the English word followed by "***meeoow***", eg, egg -> eggmeeoow and 121word -> 121wordmeeoow

Consonants are:

> bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ

Anything else is considered non-consonant.
I need to work out the rules that reverse the conversion process.  I will also need to deal with the problematic case of words that don't have one translation from code Latin to English. For example ***anmeeoow*** could have come from the English word **man**  or **an**  (to see this convert **man** from English to Code-Latin and convert **an**from English to Code-Latin).

Whenever your program gets a Code-Latin word that could have come from one of two English words it should give both options in parentheses as given in the examples below. For example, ***anmeeoow*** will be translated to ***(man or an)***.

Important: When there are two options your program should always give the word starting with a consonant  first, eg, extrameeoow -> ***(mextra or extra)***, atmeeoow -> ***(mat or at)***.

The function should be called as follows:

```
sentence = "oneeoow hankyouteeoow imeeoow ammeeoow allergicmeeoow oteeoow eggsmeeoow"
english = english_sentence(sentence)
print(english)
```

Output:

```
no thankyou (mi or i) (mam or am) (mallergic or allergic) to (meggs or eggs)
```

NOTE:
I was able to apply conversion from english to code-latin. As follows:

```
def code_latin_from_word(english):
"""Word"""
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
if english[0] in consonants:
    return english[1:] + english[0] + 'eeoow'
return english + 'meeoow'

def code_latin_from_sentence(sentence):
"""Sentence"""
return ' '.join(code_latin_from_word(w) for w in sentence.lower().split())
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, even you didn't get too far.

Comment: Acutally, I was able to convert from english to code-latin. But here, the reverse is being asked, and I need to account for ambiguities as indicated

Comment: Ok, but you need to show us your code for the reverse conversion, and ask a specific question so we can help you make that code work correctly. Otherwise, this question's likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: Have you figured out how to decide when a coded word decodes to 2 english words?

Comment: That is where I am really stuck. Especially on how to handle ambiguous cases.

Comment: Yes, that has been given in the question. The coded word -to- english words examples have been provided as above

Comment: Here's a hint. A coded word is ambiguous if & only if it ends with "meeoow". And you can easily test for that because Python strings have an `.endswith` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you the following solution, quite simple to read:

```
def english_sentence(sentence):
    consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
    english_words = [] # List to store each decoded word
    for coded_word in sentence.split():
        if coded_word.endswith("eeoow") and (coded_word[-6] in consonants):
            # Here the word is a coded word
            english_word = coded_word[-6] + coded_word[:-6]
            if (coded_word[-6] == 'm') and (coded_word[0] not in consonants):
                # Here the coded word have 2 decoding possibilities
                english_word = '(' + english_word + ' or ' + coded_word[:-6] + ')'
        english_words.append(english_word)

    return " ".join(english_words)


sentence = "oneeoow hankyouteeoow imeeoow ammeeoow allergicmeeoow oteeoow eggsmeeoow"
english = english_sentence(sentence)
print(english)  # no thankyou (mi or i) (mam or am) (mallergic or allergic) to (meggs or eggs)
```